# Should I ever use __throw_logic_error?

Tags: c++, exception

I've stumbled upon a piece of code that uses a function `std::__throw_logic_error` to throw exceptions. This function is declared in `functexcept.h` and apparently does the same as `throw logic_error(...)`. Is there a difference? What is the function for? When, if at all, should I prefer it?

Thank you.

Comment: Just as an aside, the reason such functions exist is often to support compiler options that turn features off, such as RTTI or exceptions. So it's truly nothing useful to you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general, you shouldn't use it.

The two underscores at the beginning of the name are an indication that it's a compiler-specific addition, and probably it's not even meant for "public" use, but just as a helper for internals of the standard library (I suspect that it's there to support e.g. using the library without exceptions, but I'm just guessing).

Just use `throw`.

Answer (score 8):

No, don't use it (unless you really know what you're doing). It's internal to the implementation (as all __ names are).

Comment: Is it dangerous to leave it in the code? Or is it just a bad style?

Comment: It's nonportable and it probably can disappear at any new release of the compiler.